# Proper way to exit form pyGame app. Windows cannot handle closing the window

Tags: python, loops, pygame

I'm writing app which draws analog clock based on a current time which python get by pytz and datetime. Everything works fine except shutting down a window of an app. It causes problem for windows when red X button is clicked (only when function is executed, when we select time zone). May it be caused by using nested loop?

```
import pygame
import sys
import math
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

size = 500

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size, size))
pygame.display.set_caption("CLOCK")

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 20)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


tz_London = pytz.timezone("Europe/London")
datetime_London = datetime.now(tz_London)
starting_hour_London = int(datetime_London.strftime("%H"))

# getting actual time
now = datetime.now()

starting_hour_Warsaw = int(now.strftime("%H"))
starting_minute = int(now.strftime("%M"))
starting_second = int(now.strftime("%S"))


angle_second = int(((starting_second/60) * 360) - 90)
angle_minute = ((starting_minute/60) * 360) - 90
angle_hour_Warsaw = None
angle_hour_London = None

if starting_hour_Warsaw in range(0, 12):
    angle_hour_Warsaw = ((starting_hour_Warsaw/12) * 360 + (starting_minute * 0.5) + (starting_second * (1/120))) - 90
else:
    angle_hour_Warsaw = (((starting_hour_Warsaw - 12) / 12) * 360 + (starting_minute * 0.5) + (starting_second * (1 / 120))) - 90

if starting_hour_London in range(0, 12):
    angle_hour_London = ((starting_hour_London / 12) * 360 + (starting_minute * 0.5) + (starting_second * (1 / 120))) - 90
else:
    angle_hour_London = (((starting_hour_London - 12) / 12) * 360 + (starting_minute * 0.5) + (starting_second * (1 / 120))) - 90


screen.fill((0, 0, 0))


def drawing_clock():
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0 ,0), (size/2, size/2), 200, 10)
    lenght = 190
    offset = 150
    starting_pos = (size/2,size/2)
    angles = [0, 90, 180, 270]
    # Vertical and horizontal marks
    for angle in angles:
        x = starting_pos[0] + int(math.cos(math.radians(angle))) * lenght
        y = starting_pos[1] + int(math.sin(math.radians(angle))) * lenght
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), starting_pos, (x, y), 10)
    for angle in angles:
        x = starting_pos[0] + int(math.cos(math.radians(angle))) * offset
        y = starting_pos[1] + int(math.sin(math.radians(angle))) * offset
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), starting_pos, (x, y), 10)
    # Angled marks
    angles_2 = [30,60, 120, 150, 210, 240, 300, 330]
    for angle in angles_2:
        x = starting_pos[0] + math.cos(math.radians(angle)) * lenght
        y = starting_pos[1] + math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * lenght
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), starting_pos, (x, y), 5)
    for angle in angles_2:
        x = starting_pos[0] + math.cos(math.radians(angle)) * (offset+25)
        y = starting_pos[1] + math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * (offset+25)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), starting_pos, (x, y), 10)
    # Buttons
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), (size / 8, size / 8), 40, 5)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), ((size / 8)*7, size / 8), 40, 5)

    button_London = font.render("London", False, (255, 255, 255))
    button_London_rect = button_London.get_rect(center = (size/8, size/8))
    screen.blit(button_London, button_London_rect)

    button_Warsaw = font.render("Warsaw", False, (255, 255, 255))
    button_Warsaw_rect = button_London.get_rect(center = ((size/8)*7, size/8))
    screen.blit(button_Warsaw, button_Warsaw_rect)

    pygame.display.update()


def timezone():
    tz = None
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if tz == None:
        if x > ((size/8)-20) and x < ((size/8)+20) and y > ((size/8)-20) and y < ((size/8)+20):
            tz = angle_hour_London
        elif x > (((size/8)*7)-20) and x < (((size/8)*7)+20) and y > ((size/8)-20) and y < ((size/8)+20):
            tz = angle_hour_Warsaw


    print(tz)
    clock_hands(tz)


def clock_hands(tz):
    global clock, angle_second, angle_minute, angle_hour_Warsaw, angle_hour_London
    lenght_sec = 180
    lenght_min = 150
    lenght_hours = 120
    start_pos = (size/2, size/2)

    while True:
        # Drawing each hand
        offset = 150
        angle_second += 6
        x = start_pos[0] + math.cos(math.radians(angle_second)) * lenght_sec
        y = start_pos[1] + math.sin(math.radians(angle_second)) * lenght_sec
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), start_pos, (x, y), 5)
        x_2 = start_pos[0] + math.cos(math.radians(angle_minute)) * lenght_min
        y_2 = start_pos[1] + math.sin(math.radians(angle_minute)) * lenght_min
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 255, 0), start_pos, (x_2, y_2), 5)
        x_3 = start_pos[0] + math.cos(math.radians(tz)) * lenght_hours
        y_3 = start_pos[1] + math.sin(math.radians(tz)) * lenght_hours
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 255), start_pos, (x_3, y_3), 5)


        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(1)
        # Deleting outdated hands
        # For second hand
        if angle_second in [90, 180, 270, 360, 0]:
            x_extra = start_pos[0] + math.cos(math.radians(angle_second)) * offset
            y_extra = start_pos[1] + math.sin(math.radians(angle_second)) * offset
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), start_pos, (x_extra, y_extra), 7)
            pygame.display.update()
        elif angle_second in [30, 60, 120, 150, 210, 240, 300, 330]:
            x_extra = start_pos[0] + math.cos(math.radians(angle_second)) * (offset + 25)
            y_extra = start_pos[1] + math.sin(math.radians(angle_second)) * (offset + 25)
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), start_pos, (x_extra, y_extra), 7)
            pygame.display.update()
        else:
            x_extra = start_pos[0] + math.cos(math.radians(angle_second)) * lenght_sec
            y_extra = start_pos[1] + math.sin(math.radians(angle_second)) * lenght_sec
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), start_pos, (x_extra, y_extra), 5)
            pygame.display.update()
        # For minute hand
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), start_pos, (x_2, y_2), 5)
        pygame.display.update()
        angle_minute += 0.1
        # For hour hand
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), start_pos, (x_3, y_3), 5)
        pygame.display.update()
        tz += (30/3600)

        if angle_second == 360:
            angle_second = 0

drawing_clock()

while True:
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            timezone()
```

Comment: There is an infinite loop in `clock_hands()`, so the function and the application never terminates.

Comment: Thanks for response, I'm trying to get rid off this loop. Is it possilble to iterate hands angle in main loop (in which I putted event loops)?

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten your code to merge the two while loops. The function `clock_hands()` now runs every iteration of the loop, however only increments the second hand if the new `frame` variable (which increments by 1 every loop and goes back to 0 every second) is 0, meaning that the second hand is only updated every second.

As well as the loop merge and the frame system, I have made it so that the clock is redrawn every loop, after the screen is made black, as an easier way of deleting the previous hands.

I hope this helps. If you have any questions ask them and I'll reply as soon as I can.

```
import pygame
import sys
import math
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

size = 500

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size, size))
pygame.display.set_caption("CLOCK")

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 20)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60
frame = -1
tz = None

tz_London = pytz.timezone("Europe/London")
datetime_London = datetime.now(tz_London)
starting_hour_London = int(datetime_London.strftime("%H"))

# getting actual time
now = datetime.now()

starting_hour_Warsaw = int(now.strftime("%H"))
starting_minute = int(now.strftime("%M"))
starting_second = int(now.strftime("%S"))
start_pos = (size / 2, size / 2)


angle_second = int(((starting_second/60) * 360) - 90)
angle_minute = ((starting_minute/60) * 360) - 90
angle_hour_Warsaw = None
angle_hour_London = None

if starting_hour_Warsaw in range(0, 12):
    angle_hour_Warsaw = ((starting_hour_Warsaw/12) * 360 + (starting_minute * 0.5) + (starting_second * (1/120))) - 90
else:
    angle_hour_Warsaw = (((starting_hour_Warsaw - 12) / 12) * 360 + (starting_minute * 0.5) + (starting_second * (1 / 120))) - 90

if starting_hour_London in range(0, 12):
    angle_hour_London = ((starting_hour_London / 12) * 360 + (starting_minute * 0.5) + (starting_second * (1 / 120))) - 90
else:
    angle_hour_London = (((starting_hour_London - 12) / 12) * 360 + (starting_minute * 0.5) + (starting_second * (1 / 120))) - 90


def drawing_clock():
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), (size/2, size/2), 200, 10)
    lenght = 190
    offset = 150
    starting_pos = (size / 2, size / 2)
    angles = [0, 90, 180, 270]
    # Vertical and horizontal marks
    for angle in angles:
        x = starting_pos[0] + int(math.cos(math.radians(angle))) * lenght
        y = starting_pos[1] + int(math.sin(math.radians(angle))) * lenght
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), starting_pos, (x, y), 10)
    for angle in angles:
        x = starting_pos[0] + int(math.cos(math.radians(angle))) * offset
        y = starting_pos[1] + int(math.sin(math.radians(angle))) * offset
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), starting_pos, (x, y), 10)
    # Angled marks
    angles_2 = [30,60, 120, 150, 210, 240, 300, 330]
    for angle in angles_2:
        x = starting_pos[0] + math.cos(math.radians(angle)) * lenght
        y = starting_pos[1] + math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * lenght
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), starting_pos, (x, y), 5)
    for angle in angles_2:
        x = starting_pos[0] + math.cos(math.radians(angle)) * (offset+25)
        y = starting_pos[1] + math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * (offset+25)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), starting_pos, (x, y), 10)
    # Buttons
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), (size / 8, size / 8), 40, 5)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), ((size / 8)*7, size / 8), 40, 5)

    button_London = font.render("London", False, (255, 255, 255))
    button_London_rect = button_London.get_rect(center = (size/8, size/8))
    screen.blit(button_London, button_London_rect)

    button_Warsaw = font.render("Warsaw", False, (255, 255, 255))
    button_Warsaw_rect = button_London.get_rect(center = ((size/8)*7, size/8))
    screen.blit(button_Warsaw, button_Warsaw_rect)

    pygame.display.update()


def timezone():
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if x > ((size/8)-20) and x < ((size/8)+20) and y > ((size/8)-20) and y < ((size/8)+20):
        return angle_hour_London
    elif x > (((size/8)*7)-20) and x < (((size/8)*7)+20) and y > ((size/8)-20) and y < ((size/8)+20):
        return angle_hour_Warsaw


def clock_hands(tz, should_update_second_hand):
    global clock, angle_second, angle_minute, angle_hour_Warsaw, angle_hour_London
    lenght_sec = 180
    lenght_min = 150
    lenght_hours = 120


    # Drawing each hand
    offset = 150
    if should_update_second_hand:
        angle_second += 6
    x = start_pos[0] + math.cos(math.radians(angle_second)) * lenght_sec
    y = start_pos[1] + math.sin(math.radians(angle_second)) * lenght_sec

    x_2 = start_pos[0] + math.cos(math.radians(angle_minute)) * lenght_min
    y_2 = start_pos[1] + math.sin(math.radians(angle_minute)) * lenght_min

    x_3 = start_pos[0] + math.cos(math.radians(tz)) * lenght_hours
    y_3 = start_pos[1] + math.sin(math.radians(tz)) * lenght_hours

    pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), start_pos, (x, y), 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 255, 0), start_pos, (x_2, y_2), 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 255), start_pos, (x_3, y_3), 5)

    if should_update_second_hand:
        tz += (30/3600)

    if angle_second == 360:
        angle_second = 0


while True:
    clock.tick(fps)
    frame = (frame + 1) % fps
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    drawing_clock()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            tz = timezone()

    if tz is not None:
        clock_hands(tz, frame == 0)


    pygame.display.update()
```